# Attempting to find records matching email domain with LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, select, contains

In this list I am attempting to get all `"Email Address"`'s that have a domain similar to the item collection found within the `string[]` array `CompanyDomain`. Not so sure I am getting the correct results with the `EnumerableRowCollection<Data> modelRows` and `registrationRows`. The results don't match my sql queries. Could anyone clear this up for me? Am I calling my LINQ queries incorrectly or misusing the `.Contains` function? Thank you!

```
// Get available domain names, i.e. @somecompany.com, and store into array.
string[] CompanyDomain = CompanyData.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(domain => (domain.Field<string>("Name") ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim() == Name)
    .Select(domain => domain.Field<string>("Email"))
    .ToArray();

// Cycle through this domain array.
for (int j = 0; j < CompanyDomain.Length; j++)
{
    // Create variable to hold current domain to work with.
    string companyDomainName = CompanyDomain[j];

    // Get all mods and regs containing the desired companyDomainName.
    EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> modelRows = ModelData.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(mod => (mod.Field<string>("Email Address") ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim().Contains(companyDomainName))
        .Select(mod => mod);
    EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> registrationRows = RegistrationData.AsEnumerable()
        .Where(reg => (reg.Field<string>("Email Address") ?? string.Empty).ToString().Trim().Contains(companyDomainName))
        .Select(reg => reg);
}
```

Comment: Give example of how result do not match the query.

Comment: This operation creates an excel file when it finds matching data of the domain. Basically my sql query for each domain `select * from X where email like '%' + @domain + '%'` returns around 15 sheets and the linq operation only returns around 12...

Comment: There is too much code. Visible and invisible. Can you just post a 5 line code that gives you the bad result, 5 items in the database table and the result of both code and database that differs? It will allow me to look futher. Currently I cannot find any errors in your code.

Comment: @kiev.fly Updated the code to only show what is not working.

Comment: Use fake emails to show what emails are selected by query and what e-mails are selected by linq.